# May someone recommend books about "magnetic terms"?

Tags: classical-mechanics, symplectic-geometry

Magnetic terms is a term appears in geometric mechanics and symplectic geometry. It first appeared in history maybe in 1970, in cotangent bundle reduction theory by Smale. Will someone recommend some book that give more details about how this term relates to engineering? Thanks.

Comment: If the question is not well asked, please tell me which part is not good and how to improve the question, instead of giving a -1 without saying anything.

Comment: I'm not the downvoter, but to me "how this term relates to engineering" is too vague. Are you asking for a physical system, of relevance to mechanical engineering and modeled using Hamiltonian mechanics, whose dynamics has successfully reduced through the cotangent-bundle method to Hamilton's equations for a symplectic form shifted from the canonical one by a magnetic term?

Comment: Thanks, Dave. Maybe both, the latter you said is much more prefered.